# Advanced example of RxJS5 combination with delayed observable

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

Hy, i faced a problem with RxJS Combination operators...

here is example object:

```
const userData = {
        dbKeyPath: 'www.example.com/getDbKey',
        users:[
            {name:'name1'},
            {name:'name2'},
            {name:'name3'}
        ]
    }
```

Make observable from them:

```
const userDataStream  = Rx.Observable.of(userData)
const dbKeyStream : string = this.userDataStream.mergeMap(_userData => getDbKey(_userData.dbKeyPath))
const userStream = this.userDataStream.pluck('users').mergeMap(_users=>Rx.Observable.from(_users))
```

My expected result is stream with combined observables:

```
[user[0],dbKey],[user[1],dbKey],[user[2],dbKey]...
```

It works pretty well with `withLatestFrom` operator:

```
const result = userStream.withLatestFrom(dbKeyStream) // [user, dbkey]
```

But, how can i archive same result when i apply `.delay()` operator to `dbKeyStream` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [mergeMap overload with the selectorFunc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap):

```js
const userData = {
        dbKeyPath: 'www.example.com/getDbKey',
        users:[
            {name:'name1'},
            {name:'name2'},
            {name:'name3'}
        ]
    };

function getDbKey(path) {
  return Rx.Observable.of('the-db-key:'+path)
    .do(() => console.log('fetching db key for path: '+ path))
    .delay(1000);
}

const userDataStream  = Rx.Observable.of(userData)
  .mergeMap(
    _userData => getDbKey(_userData.dbKeyPath),
    (_userData, dbKey) => _userData.users.map(_usr => ({ user: _usr, dbKey }))
  )
.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

This gives you the input object and each output value to combine together as you require.

Comment: Thank you, but i can't accept, because i need make request **only one time**, and use same result with `user`

Comment: I have updated the code example for you to see that for each `dbKey` it is only executing `getDbKey()` once and using this result for each user in the `users` array

Comment: Why did they rename `flatMap` to `mergeMap`?

Comment: Because the name `flatMap` is misleading. It uses the `.merge()` operator in its implementation as the `.concatMap` uses `.concat()` so they decided to rename it to `.mergeMap()` to let you know what is going to happen.